# using RE to print txt file

Tags: python, python-re

Im trying to print a txt file using RE to retrieve msg send out from a person

here is what the file looks like

```
[9/8/18, 10:03:17 PM] Lim :xx xx 
xx 
xx 
xx 
[10/8/18, 11:03:17 PM] Tan:yy yy 
yy 
yy 
yy 
[10/8/18, 12:03:17 PM] Lim :zz zz 
zz 
zz 
zz
[11/8/18, 10:03:17 PM] Ong:11 11
11
11
11
```

my code is

```
import re
name = "Lim"
file = open("_chat.txt", "r")
for line in file:
    z = re.findall(r"[\W\d\W\w]",line)
    if z: found = (name in line)
    if found: print (line)
```

my output is

```
[9/8/18, 10:03:17 PM] Lim :xx xx 
[10/8/18, 12:03:17 PM] Lim :zz zz
```

The result I want is

```
[14/8/18, 10:03:17 PM] Lim :xx xx 
xx 
xx 
xx 
[14/8/18, 10:03:17 PM] Lim :zz zz 
zz 
zz 
zz
```

How do I print the next few lines? There may be more than 3 lines.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I can come up with (I'm assuming there is no `[` in the messages), is a simple split :

```
with open('_chat.txt', "r") as f:
    data = f.read()

name = "Lim"
# splitting by '[' and getting every section with messages from someone
for messages in data.split('[')[1:]:
    if name in messages:
        print('[' + messages) # only Lim messages
```

If you need re you might want to look into the [multiline](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) option

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression `[\W\d\W\w]` is looking for a single character which is non-whitespace (`\W`), a number (`\d`), redundantly, non-whitespace, again, or whitespace (`\w`).  This trivially matches every possible character because every character is either whitespace or non-whitespace. It's not entirely clear what you hoped this would match, but something like

```py
found = False
with open("_chat.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        z = re.search(r"\[[^][]*\]", line)
        if z:
            found = name in line
        if found:
            print(line)
```

will pick out lines with a literal pair of square brackets and look for the `name` only on those lines.  Perhaps notice also the use of `re.search` over `re.findall` (why do you want to find all when you only care whether or not there is a match?) and the initialization of `found` before the loop, and the use of a `with` context manager around `open` (less crucial here, but a good idiom to learn).

In some more detail, `\[` matches a literal square bracket and `\]` matches a closing one; square brackets without a backslash escape match a single character out of an enumeration of cases, called a *character class,* so `[^][]` matches a character which is not (`^`) either a literal `]` or a literal `[`, and `*` repeats that regular expression zero or more times.